# jQuery Resizable: Border jumps on resize when position absolute (jsFiddle)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css-position, resizable

I've got a little niggle with a project I'm working on at the moment - when I make an anchor .resizable() which is also positioned : absolute and resize from left or top handles, the elements shifts a couple of pixels.

I thought the borders were the culprit, but when taken off, it still nudges 1 pixel along on each resize.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8sMqS/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the bug only occurs if you use a `helper`. My updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sMqS/7/) doesn't have the buggy behavior. This would suggest that it is a bug in jQueryUI and it might be worthwhile [filing a bug report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/) with them and posting the ticket here.